# Jquery button with symfony and twig

Tags: jquery, symfony, button, twig

I try to make a basic event work, I want to print something into my console when I click a button. I can't make it work with jquery and I don't know why. I have my html that is a twig file, it is the base of my website. Then I have my other twig file when I want to use my listener for my button. I took this html in the website botstrap.

My main template :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- saved from url=(0043)http://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/ -->
<html lang="en"><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
<meta name="description" content="">
<meta name="author" content="">
<link rel="icon" href="http://getbootstrap.com/favicon.ico">

<title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
{% block stylesheets %}{% endblock %}
<!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

</head>

<body>

  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
          <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
        
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">Skeletons ONLINE</a>
      </div>
      <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

        <form class="navbar-form navbar-right">
          {% block menu %}{% endblock %}

          <input type="button" value="Inscription" href="/registration" id="button_registration"/>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" class="form-control" id="input_email">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <input type="password" placeholder="Password" class="form-control" id="input_password">
          </div>
          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success" value="Sign In" id="button_login"/>
        </form>
      </div><!--/.navbar-collapse -->
    </div>
  </nav>

  <!-- Main jumbotron for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
</br>
</br>
</br>
{% block body %}{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}{% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

And my other twig file that herite form my base :

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block menu %}
<input type="button" value="Construction" href="/construction" id="button_building"/>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
<script>
 console.log("k");

 $("#button_login").click(function()
 {
  console.log("button login");
  var email = $("#input_email").val();
  var password = $("#input_password").val();

  console.log(email);
  console.log(password);

 });
 
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

So my first console.log display k into my console, but when I click my button, there is no "button login" displayed.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the first line from your second template because "A template that extends another one cannot include contents outside Twig blocks.". Besides, JQuery is already added in your base template.

You may need a "e.preventDefault();" also, because if the form is submitted the page will reload and, unless you check "Preserve log" in your browser, you wont see your console log outputs. Try this:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block menu %}
<input type="button" value="Construction" href="/construction" id="button_building"/>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
<script>
    console.log("k");

    $("#button_login").click(function(e)
    {
        e.preventDefault();
        console.log("button login");
        var email = $("#input_email").val();
        var password = $("#input_password").val();

        console.log(email);
        console.log(password);

    });

</script>

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: It i an `input type="submit"`  so yes, it will submit the form if you don't use `e.preventDefault()`

Comment: @LP154 Didn't read the base template, so my argument is invalid

Answer (score 0):

Please check below code, May be it will help, You need to put your code in click function only.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block menu %}
<input type="button" value="Construction" href="/construction" id="button_building"/>

{% endblock %}

{% block javascripts %}
<script>
 console.log("k");
    $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#button_building").click(function()
   {
          alert("Test");
  
   });
    });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```